# Triangular matrix with diagonal $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an $n\times n$ matrix with $a_{ij}=0$ if $i \geq j$. Let $v$ be the third column in A. Show that $A^2v=0$.

I have managed to prove that $Au=0$ if $u$ is the second column. If someone can give a little advice on how to write the elements of $A^2v$ as a sum I think that I can solve it.

My attempt is: $$A^2=a^2_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}a_{ji}$$ and $A^2v$ would be somethig like $$v_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}a_{ji}a_{j3}.$$

If this sum is right, I can just use the definition of the triangular matrix, what can i do if this sum is wrong?

Comment: You already managed to show that $Au=0$ for the second column. Then it is just the same argument for $A^2$ and $v$,  since the zeros go one up in $A^2$.

Comment: Ok, i know that it's the same argument, but i use the summatory for the first one (really easy to write), but for the second it's kinda hard.

Comment: Then don't use "the summatory" but rather argue why the result is the same as $Au$, which is zero as you know.